# Make axes unequal in matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In MATLAB, using `surf` a colleague was able to make the heatmap/surface below.  I have been trying to generate plots using the same data in both *matplotlib* and *seaborn*, but cannot seem to find any way to make the x-axis unequally spaces like MATLAB does.

Is there a way out of the box to make sure my x-axis does not become equally spaced?

[image]

Comment: `ax.set_xticks([-5, -3. -2, -1. -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn's heatmap (based on matplotlib's `imshow`) always creates categorical axes. You can use matplotlib's `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` to set numeric x and y values for the cell edges.

Here is an example. Note that the number of data values is one less in both directions compared to the number of edges.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)
xs = [-5, -3, -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5]
ys = np.arange(1500, 5001, 500)
data = gaussian_filter(np.random.rand(len(ys) - 1, len(xs) - 1), 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(xs, ys, data, cmap='inferno')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_yticks(ys)
ax.grid(True, axis='both', color='skyblue')
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.pcolor with uneven cell borders]